# How to display simple 3D modells in .NET C#

Tags: .net, 3d

I am simulating 2 cars on a road, with several engine, steer and brake related parameters that change the movement of the cars on the fiktive road during the simulation. I have nice graphs of the process but it would be nice to display the movement of the cars and the line of the road. For visualization's sake, like when you can see an accident visualized in TV in the eveneing news.

Is there any freely available 3D engine for #C with what I could visualize this scenario? No raytracing or Z buffering needed, just to display several simple objects in 3D with a movable point of view. I also would like to avoid DirectX, it seems to complex for me for this relativly simple task.

Comment: You need Z buffering, otherwise you will for example draw the interior of your car over the exterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx) runs in .net and has well-documented ways to load 3D models and textures. It is also fairly light-weight, which seems appropriate for your task.

There is an open source clone, [Mono Game](http://www.monogame.net/), in case you want to support non-windows platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with umlum that XNA is a suitable choice for you.

Below is a free online tutorial that might help you quickly get started with XNA and 3D Graphics.

http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/3d-tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how much detail you wish to show, you may be able to get away with simply using XAML and a Viewport3D within a WPF application

It's pretty straightforward and suffices for small tasks - the performance isn't great, but is sufficient for a scene with a small triangle count